# Android HTTP Methods Rest API

Tags: android, node.js, rest, api, http

I am working on a project on android and I want to implement the functionality of my application on an API written in Node JS and use it with HTTP requests.
I am searching for an (open source) HTTP API (CRUD System) that I can use in my android application in order to make HTTP requests to my API (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).
What are you suggesting me? Which are the best solutions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend OSS "Fuel".
https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel

I created a sample application of API request using Fuel.
https://github.com/y-okudera/FuelSampleApp

I hope this will be of some help.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will take a look!